# Getting mapping error. After dragging table with xml fields into dbml file and then compiling

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql, silverlight-3.0

**"Error 1 DBML1005: Mapping between DbType 'Xml' and Type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' in Column 'XML_LAYOUT' of Type 'QUEST_BLOCK' is not supported."** 
The above is the error am getting. What am doing is dragging a table with xml fields as columns from server explorer into a dbml file. After that when i compile i am getting the above error. Now after that i changed server datatype to blank. Now the program compiles successfully. But at runtime if i query the table directly using WCF in silverlight the function is showing error. After a debug i found that the select statement on the table is returning the rows in the funtiion, however the error is produced in the reference file in the following function.

```
Public Function EndGetQuestionListRecord1(ByVal result As System.IAsyncResult) As ServiceReference1.QUEST_BLOCK Implements ServiceReference1.Medex.EndGetQuestionListRecord1
  Dim _args((0) - 1) As Object
  Dim _result As ServiceReference1.QUEST_BLOCK = CType(MyBase.EndInvoke("GetQuestionListRecord1", _args, result),ServiceReference1.QUEST_BLOCK)
  Return _result
End Function
```

Hope someone around here could resolve this error...

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Answer (score 0):

rideonscreen, recently I started getting the same type of error. In my case I get it dragging a stored procedure with a XML input parameter.

I wonder whether you managed to resolve the issue and how.

I googled and found some articles:
http://dev.techmachi.com/?p=319
http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/505990.aspx
http://www.jonathanjungman.com/blog/post/Visual-Studio-Build-failed-due-to-validation-errors-in-dbml-file.aspx

"devenv /resetskippkgs" helps, but next day the issue appears again.

What is also interesting that I do not touch the LINQ2SQL model (dbml file) at all. The code there is the same for a long time. The issues is definitely exclusively related to Visual Studio.

P.S. I am thinking to migrate to EF.